# Animal Crossing New Horizons, What's different between simple / mini DIY workbench

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I got simply DIY workbench with me, and I bring it to take off to other island, and it's fine until now.

Somehow, I found there is a **mini DIY workbench**.

Just wondering : What's different between them ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only difference is the look and how much physical space they take up in the world. You can craft the exact same recipes on both.